# How to save related Models in one transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  validates :customer, presence: true
end
```

Then, in my controller, I would expect to be able to create both in
"one" sweep:

```
@customer = Customer.new
@customer.contacts.build
@customer.save
```

This, fails (unfortunately translations are on, It translates to
something like: Contact: customer cannot be blank.)

```
@customer.errors.messages #=> :contacts=>["translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.customer.attributes.contacts.invalid"]}
```

When inspecting the models, indeed, `@customer.contacts.first.customer`
is `nil`. Which, somehow, makes sense, since the `@customer` has not
been saved, and thus has no `id`.

How can I build such associated models, then save/create them, so that:

- No models are persisted if one is invalid,
- the errors can be read out in one list, rather then combining the
  error-messages from all the models,
- and keep my code concise?

Comment: My first thought - don't validate the presence of a customer if you always create a contact through a customer. Or at least put an :if statement there and exclude the situation when the customer is a new record.

Comment: add `:inverse_of` to the relationship declaration.

Comment: @j03w: inverse_of indeed got rid of that validation: it is the solution. Can you add that, so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [rails api doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)

> If you are going to modify the association (rather than just read from it), then it is a good idea to set the :inverse_of option on the source association on the join model. This allows associated records to be built which will automatically create the appropriate join model records when they are saved. (See the ‘Association Join Models’ section above.)

So simply add `:inverse_of` to relationship declaration (`has_many`, `belongs_to` etc) will make `active_record` save models in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

- The first thing that came to my mind - just get rid of that validation.
- Second thing that came to mind - save the customer first and them build the contact.
- Third thing: use `:inverse_of` when you declare the relationship. Might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can save newly created related models in a single database transaction but not with a single call to `save` method. Some ORMs (e.g. LINQToSQL and Entity Framework) can do it but ActiveRecord can't. Just use `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` method to make sure that either both models are saved or none of them. More about ActiveRecord and transactions here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks: I have plans to move all this building into a Builder class in some future. `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` will come in handy then. For now, I could solve it, by marking the relations with `inverse_of` as was provided in a comment.